# why is showing that $f(H) \subseteq H$ the same as showing that $(y \in H \implies f(y) \in H)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

While I was reading a proof about the diagonalizability of symmetric matrices I got a bit lost the author was supposed to show that $f(H) \subseteq H$ but he ended up showing that

> $y \in H \implies f(y) \in H$ for all $y$

claiming it's the same thing

I would say because $y$ is arbitrary here $f(y)$ is practically the same as $f(H)$ since $y \in H$ looking at it this way it makes some sense to me but I'm still confused why those two statements are equivalent.

Please could anybody here clearly explain why?

Comment: I do believe that $f(A)$ for some set $A \subseteq D$ where $D$ is the domain of $f$ is defined as the set of all values of $f(a) \space \forall a \in A$. That would make the two statements equivalent.

Comment: @TimTheEnchanter
thank you ! now I get it.

$f(H) = \{f(y) | \forall y \in H \}$

so showing that $y \in H \implies f(y) \in H$ means showing that every element of $f(H)$ is an element of $H$ which is equivalent to $f(H) \subseteq H$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a systematic, "formal" derivation. The definition of $X \subseteq Y$ is $\forall x.x\in X \Rightarrow x\in Y$. The definition of $f(H)$ is $\{f(y)\mid y\in H\}$ or more explicitly $\{z\mid\exists y.y\in H\land z = f(y)\}$. We can now just calculate: $$\begin{align}
f(H)\subseteq H
& \iff \forall x. x\in f(H) \Rightarrow x\in H \\
& \iff \forall x. x\in \{f(y)\mid y\in H\} \Rightarrow x \in H \\
& \iff \forall x. (\exists y.y\in H\land x = f(y) ) \Rightarrow x \in H \\
& \iff \forall x. \forall y. (y\in H\land x = f(y)) \Rightarrow x \in H \\
& \iff \forall x. \forall y. y\in H \Rightarrow f(y) \in H \\
& \iff \forall y. y\in H \Rightarrow f(y) \in H
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you wrote that “$f(y)$ is practically the same thing as $f(H)$ since $y\in H$”. It happens that $f(y)$ is the image of $y$, whereas $f(H)$ is the *set* of *all* images of *all* elements of $H$. So, yes, asserting that $f(H)\subseteq H$ actually *is* the same thing as asserting that $(\forall y\in H):f(y)\in H$.

Answer (score 2):

Saying $f(H) \subseteq H$ is saying that $f$ takes each element of $H$ into $H$. Thus for all $y \in H$, $f(y) \in H$ and the statement $y \in H \Rightarrow f(y) \in H$ holds.

Conversely, if the implication $y \in H \Rightarrow f(y) \in H$ holds, $f(H) \subseteq H$ becuase by the implication $f(y) \in H$ for all $y \in H$.

Answer (score 1):

> **Proposition 0.** Given a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and subsets $A \subseteq X, B \subseteq Y$, the following are equivalent:
>
> - $\forall x \in X(x \in A \rightarrow f(x) \in B)$
> - $f(A) \subseteq B$

*Proof.*

The following are equivalent:

- $\forall x \in X(x \in A \rightarrow f(x) \in B)$
- $\forall x \in X(x \in A \rightarrow x \in f^{-1}(B))$
- $A \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$
- $f(A) \subseteq B$